# Does nodes() or openxml returns rows in same order as it finds in xml?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, openxml

I have an xml which i need to parse using openxml or nodes(). The xml contains few child tags that repeat with different values, as below.

```
<root>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>12</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>15</value>
<root>
```

For my code it is very important that i get all these rows returned in same order as in xml. I googled and gogled but nothing tells me if the @mp:id is always returned in same order as in xml. Or if nodes() return values in same order as it encounters them.

All I want to know if I can trust any of those two methods and be happy with proper order of rows.

P.S. excuse any errors or mistakes in above text, I dont enjoy typing codes in an android window either.

Comment: you can use order by and get the order that you want. If not, nothings make sure to get the same order as you can see in the xml, because, also, there is no "order" on the xml: You can change the order of the lines and will be the same attributes (considering not changing of node)

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem i am facing. The order of the xml tags means the order in which i store, say i have hourly values, and order of those tags denote the hours, starting from 0. I am getting this xml from 3rd party and I can not control the structure. If i had designed i would had used ids :-/

Comment: Why the question is tagged as OpenXML? OpenXML is used for saving documents, spreadsheets etc. :). I suppose you meant just a normal XML :).

Comment: @LukaszM: [`OPENXML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) has been a Transact-SQL function long before saving spreadsheets as XML was in anyone's mind. Asking 'should I use .nodes or openxml' is *very* well understood what it means in T-SQL community.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: You are right, thanks for the explanation. I associated term `openxml` more with office documents than SQL and that's why it confused me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number` on the shredded XML like this.

```
declare @XML xml= 
'<root>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>12</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>15</value>
</root>'

select value
from
  (
  select T.N.value('.', 'int') as value,
         row_number() over(order by T.N) as rn 
  from @xml.nodes('/root/value') as T(N)
  ) as T
order by T.rn
```

[Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx)

Update:

You can also use a numbers table like this;

```
declare @XML xml= 
'<root>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>12</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>15</value>
</root>';

with N(Number) as
(
  select Number
  from master..spt_values
  where type = 'P'
)
select @XML.value('(/root/value[sql:column("N.Number")])[1]', 'int')
from N
where N.Number between 1 and @XML.value('count(/root/value)', 'int')
order by N.Number
```

Comment: But this gives you a dense rank ove the projection of `.nodes`. It does not guarantee that `.nodes` *itself* spit out the rows in the order of the document...

Comment: @RemusRusanu It uses row_number over the internal id created by the Table Valued Function XML Reader step in the execution plan. Are you saying that that action does not number the rows in the XML sequentially?

Comment: Exactly, it is not documented to do so. Whether it does or does not, frankly I don't know. But even if it did, w/o being guaranteed, it can change with next CU... I fact, I wouldn't be at all surprised if projecting `.nodes` from an XML column with an XML index on it produces unexpected order, but I'm speculating.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Have a look at [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190769(v=sql.105).aspx). Says "Table-valued Function XML Reader inputs an XML BLOB as a parameter and produces a row set representing XML nodes in XML document order." Does this qualify as documented behavior?

Answer (score 0):

XPath allows you to select nodes explicitly by ordinal: `'/root[1]/value[1]'` is the first element, `'/root[1]/value[2]'` is the second etc. Also  could use `'(/root/value)[1]'` and `'(/root/value[2])'`. This way you can select exactly the element you want, and selecting element 1 then element 2 then element 3 etc will give you controlled order. Slow, but controlled.

*Updated* P.S. Wouldn't this be nice to be true?

```
declare @x xml = '<root>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>12</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>15</value>
<root>';

select x.value(N'position()', N'int') as position,
  x.value(N'.', 'int') as value
  from @x.nodes(N'//root/value') t(x)
```

Unfortunately, is not...

```
Msg 2371, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
XQuery [value()]: 'position()' can only be used within a predicate or XPath selector
```

And the existence of this error makes me worry that order *may* be broken sometimes...

Comment: Speed is a critical factor :-) i have already started using openxml, but i would still like a confirmation that i can be sure about the order. In practice i have never seen @mp:id being out of order, still confirmation from someone experienced would be good.

Comment: If order guarantee is not in MSDN spec (and is not) then none can add a confirmation. I never seen it out of order either, but that's no proof.

Comment: The reason for not being able to use `position()` like that is explained [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/383888/fully-support-position-in-xquery) by Michael on `2008-12-03 16:28`.

Comment: I don't think the above link to Michael's article works any more